# How can you log every command typed

Tags: shell, security, command-history, history

**How can you log every command someone has entered into the shell?**

I'm asking on both the basis of protecting yourself if you are logged into someone else's server and something breaks, or if someone else is logged into your server  (either intentionally or maliciously).

Even a novice can [bypass history](http://www.guyrutenberg.com/2011/05/10/temporary-disabling-bash-history/) with `unset history` or create a new shell to hide their tracks.

I'm curious how the senior Linux admins track what commands have been entered or what changes made to the system.

Comment: Another way to bypass bash history is to put leading space before command.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Check out [auditd](https://linux.die.net/man/8/auditd). If you add

```
-a exit,always -F arch=b64 -S execve
-a exit,always -F arch=b32 -S execve
```

to `/etc/audit/audit.rules` every executed commands will be logged. See: [https://whmcr.com/2011/10/14/auditd-logging-all-commands/](https://whmcr.com/?p=251)

Then send it to a syslog server.

Comment: Surely `execve` is not the only syscall you need to log. Why not `execvp` as well? Or `execl`? etc.

Comment: Actually, I noticed that in the man page for `exec` it says that "The `exec()`  family  of functions replaces the current process image with a new process image.  The functions described in this manual page are front-ends for `execve(2)`." So while I'm not sure about `execveat` I can feel assured about the `exec` family.

Comment: For people stumbling upon the broken link: https://security.blogoverflow.com/2013/01/a-brief-introduction-to-auditd/

Comment: you can also make a look at tlog. it's not yet in debian (https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=886927) but integrates very will into cockpit and is natively supported on redhat.

Comment: In Debian 10, the config file will change constantly, use `/etc/audit/rules.d/audit.rules` instead.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the **script** command. This command is not included in POSIX, but you'll find it useful to store in a file all keystrokes as well as output and error messages. You can later view the file. If you are doing some important work and wish to keep a log of all your activities, you should invoke this command immediately after you log in:

**$ script**
**Script started, file is typescript**
**$ _**                                *Note that this is another shell--child of the login shell*

The prompt returns and all your keystrokes (including the one used to backspace) that you now enter here get recorded in the file 'typescript'. After your recording is over, you can terminate the session by entering **exit**.
Note: If you enter **script filename**, the session will be stored in the file **filename** rather than **typescript**, i.e, typescript is the default if no specific filename is specified.

You can now use **cat filename** or **cat typescript**, whichever the case may be, to view the recorded session.

If you wish to append a new session to an old file use:
**script -a**                                                                           *Appends the new session to typescript, same default rule applies here too*

This is one way in which a system admin can keep track of the sessions. Hope it has been informative and useful. Cheers!

Comment: That is incredibly easy to subvert: (1) open `view`. (2) Execute any commands you like using `:! sudo whatever` (3) exit view. (4) Tell the auditor you just looked at a data file, and in read-only mode anyway. Neither history nor script will tell on you.

Comment: This was a super helpful tip. I think this is great for when the actor you want to monitor isn't malicious - i.e. yourself, if you just want a log of everything conducted during a session. This can be handy in some heavy debugging sessions.