# How to know log the full script name executed by user?

Tags: shell-script, solaris, ksh

I want to log the full name of the script executed by the user including the options/arguments he provided to that script.

I was able to achieve some success using `basename` and `whoami` but it does not give me the arguments.

**Example:** let's assume user ran script like this

```
root@host1:./collect_user_summary.ksh -h 20 -l 10 -x local
```

**Desired Output in my log file**:

```
"collect_user_summary.ksh -h 20 -l 10 -x local"
```

**What I have managed to achieve:** with `basename` and `whoami` I was able to get

```
"collect_user_summary.ksh  username"
```

**My environment**: Solaris 10, kornshell.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you log every command typed](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86000/how-can-you-log-every-command-typed)

Comment: Does `$*` (or `$@`) work in `ksh`?

Comment: Auditing.  Anything else runs as the user and therefore the use can modify or delete your data.  Read http://cuddletech.com/blog/pivot/entry.php?id=1081

Answer (score 0):

Update: I see most of you pointing me to logging of all commands entered in terminal. I dont want that. All i want to do is whenever someone execute my script i just need to log what options he gave along with script name.

After thinking for a while i was able to figure it out.
I am using the following method to achieve it.
**Sample Script:**

```
#!/bin/ksh
NAME=`basename $0`
echo `date` $WHOAMI ran this script $NAME with options -h $HVARIABLE -l $LVARIABLE -x $LOCALVARIABLE >> scripts.log
.
..
..
....
echo "SUCCESS" >> scripts.log
exit 0
```

By including these 2 lines in all my scripts i was able to log who is doing what and what options they are providing.

Comment: 1. permissions/ownership may be a problem if multiple users write to the same log file.  pre-create the log file with either 660, 664 or 666 perms. 2. try `echo $(date) $WHOAMI ran this script $NAME with options:  "$@" >>> scripts.log`  - `"$@"` lists all command-line options.  and use `$()` rather than backticks...backticks are deprecated and mess up quoting.

Comment: Permissions is not a problem for my log file, since only users with root previlage can execute our scripts. I have't tried $@ in KSH. I find backticks workng lot better than brackets in my solaris & KSH combination.

Comment: 1. "$@" works in ksh.  2. You can't easily nest backticks and they mess up quoting.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449778/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-instead-of-backticks-in-shell-scripts

Comment: @cas I get your point. I never got a situation to nest multiple variables into a single variable, backticks and pipes were sufficient. Thanks for your tip. It'll be useful someday down the road.