# `sudo` session logging in binary?

Tags: sudo, logs

I recently started working on sudo and i am trying to explore and understand the different aspects of sudo logging - I/O and audit.

I'm using sudo 1.8.22 package on Red hat linux 6.7. Does `sudo` write any logs in binary format; if yes

1. which logs are written in binary?
2. which version of sudo is it?
3. does this happen only on a specific flavor of unix os - rhel, aix, debian?

The sudo I/O logs generated for me on RHEL and sudo 1.8.22 seems to be in ascii/text format and not binary.

Answer (score 0):

No `sudo` only logs as ASCII.

The only additional things that I'm aware of, with respect to `sudo`, are to enable the `log_input` and `log_output` which do nothing more than act as the `script` command does, and capture the commands passed into `sudo` and their output and log these as well.

For reference on these see this U&L Q&A titled: [How to log commands within a "sudo su -"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108577/how-to-log-commands-within-a-sudo-su).

For additional logging that is likely more what you want, I'd take a look at `auditd` instead. It can log pretty extensively what's going on with respect to a Linux node.

#### Alternatives, if you're interested...

In addition to `sudo` there's alternatives there as well - https://www.sudo.ws/other.html both opensource and commercial. I've not mucked with many of these, except for Centrify (commercial) which provides an alternative tool to `sudo`, called `dzdo`. It has centralized logging and policies etc. which can be managed across a fleet of Linux nodes.

The closest thing I've seen to `dzdo` that's opensource is [FreeIPA's](https://www.freeipa.org/page/Main_Page) centrally managed `sudo` polices and logging.

#### References

- [Linux file access monitoring](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12247/linux-file-access-monitoring/12251#12251)
- [How can you log every command typed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86000/how-can-you-log-every-command-typed/86003#86003)